# 'invalid multibyte character' when reading text file

Tags: r, character-encoding

For an internal project we have to read some extremely large files (>2.5GB). We used to read these files by calling

`laf_open(detect_dm_csv(filename = file_path))`

and then looping over each line, reading substrings, and manually creating a dataframe from those. For some files, this works just fine, but for others, this method has failed:

`invalid multibyte string at '<e4> '`

When looking at the files, I can see that each row contains this multibyte character in the very same position (there is always a spot where the string shows `\xe4`). My hypothesis is that the files are being read in the wrong encoding. But I don't see how `detect_dm_csv` allows one to choose the encoding to use. Any ideas how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

reading csv with encoding parameters can be like:

```
df<- read.csv(file_path, 
                encoding = "iso-8859-1", 
                header = TRUE, 
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: I found this just after asking the question, but neither ASCII, UTF-8 nor UTF-16 seemed to work out. This is especially strange as in the past the very same code ought to have worked. Any ideas what encoding this might be? It should really just be a normal csv file from a German company.

Comment: Maybe this iso-8859-1. Because in German '\xe4' is "ä"

Comment: I have figured out that ANSI is the correct encoding. However, simply loading the file with that encoding doesn't seem to suffice. Rather, I need to change the system locale to ```de_DE```. But then I cannot open other R files, so I have to set the locale to ```de_DE```, load my file, construct some data frame, and then set the locale back to ```de_DE.utf-8```. There has to be a better way, right?

Comment: You can use Sys.setlocale("required encoding") before opening the files and after again the Sys.setlocale("initial encoding") to return the locale back to it's initial state. In order to find the initial state use Sys.getlocale()